# Count Response once in 30 days SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have a customer respond to the same survey in 30 days more than once, I only want to count it once. Can someone show me code to do that please?

```
create table #Something
(
         CustID Char(10),
    SurveyId char(5),
    ResponseDate datetime
)

insert #Something
select 'Cust1', '100', '5/6/13' union all
select 'Cust1', '100', '5/13/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '4/20/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '5/22/13'


select distinct custid, SurveyId, Count(custid) as CountResponse from #Something
group by CustID, SurveyId
```

The above code only gives me the total count of Response, not sure how to code to count only once per 30 day period.

The output I'm looking for should be like this:

```
CustomerID     SurveyId    CountResponse
Cust1          100         1
Cust2          100         2
```

Comment: by "30 day period" do you mean a rolling 30 day window, or within the same month?

Comment: It sounds like rolling 30 day window, which is what makes it excruciatingly difficult to solve relationally.

Comment: That's a hard one to solve relationally, because state about which surveys have been counted must be maintained. It's an interesting and challenging question though and you should have received many more up votes for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on the theory that you want your periods calculated as 30 days from the first time a survey is submitted, here is a (gross) solution.

```
declare @Something table
(
    CustID Char(10),
    SurveyId char(5),
    ResponseDate datetime
)

insert @Something
select 'Cust1', '100', '5/6/13' union all
select 'Cust1', '100', '5/13/13' union all
select 'Cust1', '100', '7/13/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '4/20/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '5/22/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '7/20/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '7/24/13' union all
select 'Cust2', '100', '9/28/13' 

--SELECT CustID,SurveyId,COUNT(*) FROM (

select a.CustID,a.SurveyId,b.ResponseStart,--CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart),
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart) > 30 
    THEN ((CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart))-(CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart) % 30))/30+1
    ELSE 1
END CustomPeriod -- defines periods 30 days out from first entry of survey
from @Something a
inner join
(select CustID,SurveyId,MIN(ResponseDate) ResponseStart
from @Something
group by CustID,SurveyId) b
on a.SurveyId=b.SurveyId
and a.CustID=b.CustID
group by a.CustID,a.SurveyId,b.ResponseStart,
CASE 
    WHEN CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart) > 30 
    THEN ((CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart))-(CONVERT(int,a.ResponseDate-b.ResponseStart) % 30))/30+1
    ELSE 1
END

--) x GROUP BY CustID,SurveyId
```

At the very least you'd probably want to make the CASE statement a function so it reads a bit cleaner.  Better would be defining explicit windows in a separate table.  This may not be feasible if you want to avoid situations like surveys returned at the end of period one followed by another in period two a couple days later.

You should consider handling this on input if possible.  For example, if you are identifying a customer in an online survey, reject attempts to fill out a survey.  Or if someone is mailing these in, make the data entry person reject it if one has come within 30 days.

Or, along the same lines as "wild and crazy", add a bit and an INSERT trigger.  Only turn the bit on if no surveys of that type for that customer found within the time period.

Overall, phrasing the issue a little more completely would be helpful.  However I do appreciate the actual coded example.

Comment: I appreciate the other options you've mentioned, but they are not within my scope, as data comes from various big data stores across the org. So, can't touch the source database or input systems. Thanks, your code returns what I expected with some test data. I have to make a table of all responses received and will try this - the logic is actually too complicated (at least for me as I consider myself mid-level) as I have to count one response/per survey/ per customer/per group/per 30 days!

Comment: This is part of the code for a big report where the user is able to select date range and if they select YTD, then I have to see that this does not cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SQL Server guy, but in Oacle if you subtract integer values from a 'date', you're effectively subtracting "days," so something like this could work:

```
SELECT custid, surveyid
FROM Something a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Something b
    WHERE a.custid = b.custid
    AND a.surveyid = b.surveyid
    AND b.responseDate between a.responseDate AND a.responseDate - 30
    );
```

To get your counts (if I udnerstand what you're asking for):

```
-- Count of times custID returned surveyID, not counting same
-- survey within 30 day period.
SELECT custid, surveyid, count(*) countResponse
FROM Something a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Something b
    WHERE a.custid = b.custid
    AND a.surveyid = b.surveyid
    AND b.responseDate between a.responseDate AND a.responseDate - 30
    )
GROUP BY custid, surveyid
```

UPDATE: Per the case raised below, this actually wouldn't quite work. What you should probably do is iterate through your `something` table and insert the rows for the surveys you want to keep in a `results` table, then compare against the `results` table to see if there's already been a survey received in the last 30 days you want considered. I could show you how to do something like this in oracle PL/SQL, but I don't know the syntax off hand for SQL server. Maybe someone else who knows sql server wants to steal this strategy to code up an answer for you, or maybe this is enough for you to go on.

Comment: This would not work. Imagine the case where a person responds every day for three months and one day (to take February into account). Clearly, the count should be three. What would your query produce? 1?

Answer (score 0):

Call me wild and crazy, but I would solve this problem by storing more state with each survey. The approach I would take is to add a `bit` type column that indicates whether a particular survey should be counted (i.e., a `Countable` column). This solves the *tracking of state* problem inherent in solving this relationally.

I would set values in `Countable` to 1 upon insertion, if no survey with the same `CustID`/`SurveyId` can be found in the preceding 30 days with a `Countable` set to 1. I would set it to 0, otherwise.

Then the problem becomes trivially solvable. Just group by `CustID`/`SurveyId` and sum up the values in the `Countable` column.

One caveat of this approach is that it imposes that surveys must be added in chronological order and cannot be deleted without a recalculation of `Countable` values.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what "tetch' tried to code below. I have to do one more step after this - which would be counting the num of rows in the result set that he has posted. I'm sort of a mid level sql coder and this is quite complicated for me to code.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is one approach which yields your example output. However, if you add a `select 'Cust1', '100', '4/20/13'`, the result will still be `Cust1          100         1` because they are all within 30 days of each prior survey response and so only the first one would be counted. Is this the desired behavior?

```
SELECT     CustID, SurveyID, COUNT(*) AS CountResponse
FROM         #SurveysTaken
WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                      (SELECT     1
                        FROM          #SurveysTaken AS PriorSurveys
                        WHERE      (CustID = #SurveysTaken.CustID)
                               AND (SurveyId = #SurveysTaken.SurveyId)
                               AND (ResponseDate >= DATEADD(d, - 30, #SurveysTaken.ResponseDate))
                               AND (ResponseDate < #SurveysTaken.ResponseDate)))
GROUP BY CustID, SurveyID
```

Alternatively, you could break the year into arbitrary 30 day periods, resetting with each new year.

```
SELECT     CustID, SurveyID, COUNT(*) AS CountResponse
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT CustID, SurveyID, YEAR(ResponseDate) AS RepsonseYear,
                              DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, ResponseDate) / 30 AS ThirtyDayPeriod
              FROM          #SurveysTaken) AS SurveysByPeriod
GROUP BY CustID, SurveyID
```

You could also just go by month.

```
SELECT     CustID, SurveyID, COUNT(*) AS CountResponse
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT CustID, SurveyID, YEAR(ResponseDate) AS ResponseYear,
                              MONTH(ResponseDate) AS ResponseMonth
              FROM          #SurveysTaken) AS SurveysByMonth
GROUP BY CustID, SurveyID
```

You could use 30 day periods from an arbitrary epoch date. (Perhaps by pulling the date the survey was first created from another query?)

```
SELECT     CustID, SurveyID, COUNT(*) AS CountResponse
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT CustID, SurveyID, DATEDIFF(D, '1/1/2013', ResponseDate) / 30 AS ThirtyDayPeriod
                       FROM          #SurveysTaken) AS SurveysByPeriod
GROUP BY CustID, SurveyID
```

One final variation on arbitrary thirty periods is to base them on the first time the customer ever responded to the survey in question.

```
SELECT     CustID, SurveyID, COUNT(*) AS CountResponse
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT CustID, SurveyID, DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                                  (SELECT     MIN(ResponseDate)
                                                    FROM          #SurveysTaken AS FirstSurvey
                                                    WHERE      (CustID = #SurveysTaken.CustID)
                                                           AND (SurveyId = #SurveysTaken.SurveyId)), ResponseDate) / 30 AS ThirtyDayPeriod
                       FROM          #SurveysTaken) AS SurveysByPeriod
GROUP BY CustID, SurveyID
```

There is one issue that you run into with the epoch/period trick which is that the counted surveys occur only once per period but aren't necessarily 30 days apart.

Comment: None of this properly handles a rolling thirty day window which is what the person who asked the question desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to handle it I believe. I tested quickly, and it worked on the small sample of records so I'm hopeful it will help you out. Best of luck.

```
SELECT s.CustID, COUNT(s.SurveyID) AS SurveyCount
FROM #something s
INNER JOIN (SELECT CustID, SurveyId, ResponseDate
            FROM (SELECT #Something.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY ResponseDate ASC) AS RN
            FROM #something) AS t
            WHERE RN = 1 ) f ON s.CustID = f.CustID
WHERE s.ResponseDate BETWEEN f.ResponseDate AND f.ResponseDate+30
GROUP BY s.CustID
HAVING COUNT(s.SurveyID) > 1
```

Comment: But this one returned count as 2 for CustId 1. Sorry, but this did not work.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then. I thought you wanted to count those that had the survey more than once within 30 days. CustID 1 had the survey twice within a 30 day period--once on 5/6 and once on 5/13. CustID 2 did not have the survey more than once within 30 days so I excluded that ID.

Even if I've misunderstood your intention, you should be able to tweak this very easily into what you need. It gives you an automated, rolling 30 day period and aggregates counts for filtering in any way you like. Either way, if you've gotten a solution you're happy with, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, which may be the source of your difficulty.

```
insert #Something values
('Cust3', '100', '1/1/13'),
('Cust3', '100', '1/20/13'),
('Cust3', '100', '2/10/13')
```

Should the count for Cust3 be 1 or 2?  Is the '2/10/13' response invalid because it was less than 30 days after the '1/20/13' response?  Or is the '2/10/13' response valid because the '1/20/13' is invalidated by the '1/1/13' response and therefore more than 30 days after the previous valid response?

Comment: I talked to the Client as this was my confusion also. They want the rolling 30 day period - so in your example, the count would be 2 because 1/20 is outside the 30 day period from 1/1.

If there was another row ('Cust3', '100', '2/27/13'), then this shouldn't be counted since it is within 30 days of 2/10.

If there was another row ('Cust3', '100', '3/15/13'), then this would be counted since it is 30 days after 2/10.

Can someone show me how to code this?